# Lerna doesn't start webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, lerna

I have a `webpack.config.js` in my root directory (outside the directory that contains the `packages*.json` files) and when I start `lerna run build` then I have this error:

```html
**ERROR OUTPUT**
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~prebuild: access-ninja@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: access-ninja@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/packages/access-ninja/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/packages/access-ninja/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/packages/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/development/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/dev/node_modules/.bin:/home/user/node_modules/.bin:/home/node_modules/.bin:/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/home/user/bin/Sencha/Cmd:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/opt/maven-3.5.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: CWD: /home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/packages/access-ninja
10 silly lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack --progress --mode development' ]
11 silly lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle access-ninja@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: access-ninja@1.0.0 build: `webpack --progress --mode development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1001:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid access-ninja@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/user/dev/development/6.3_sources/portal-ui/react/packages/access-ninja
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-16-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v11.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error access-ninja@1.0.0 build: `webpack --progress --mode development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the access-ninja@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is the structure in my monorepo:

```
packages/
├── portal-ui
│   └── package.json
├── access-ninja
        └── package.json
```

I see that webpack starts, but I don't know what it needs to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add the `--config` parameter to defined where the build script is, because now it's looking inside the package folder.

`"build": "webpack --config ../../webpack.config.js --progress --mode development"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great